# Issue with replacing multiple lines in xml during maven build

Tags: maven, build, ant, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-ant-tasks

I need to replace mutliple lines in `.wsdd` file in `war` generated after my `maven` build.

I am using `antrun-maven-plugin` and `ant's replace task` for this purpose.

Below is the snippet from `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>com.github.odavid.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>antrun-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <executions>
    <execution>
     <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
       <target>
        <ant antfile="replace.xml">
         <target name="replace-config"/>    
        </ant>
       </target>
      </configuration>
     <goals>
      <goal>run</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
   </executions></plugin>
```

Here the `replace.xml` contains `ant` target to actually replace the multiline token and updating final `war` with replaced `.wsdd` file, below is part where we replace the multiline token in `.wsdd` file.

```
<target name ="replace-config">
<echo>********** Replacing tokens in server-config.wsdd file *************</echo>
<replace dir="${basedir}/target/as_gen/WEB-INF/" >
    <include name="server-config.wsdd"/>
    <replacetoken><![CDATA[<requestFlow>      
                             <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">        
                                 <parameter name="scope" value="session"/>      
                             </handler>      
                             <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.JWSHandler">        
                                <parameter name="scope" value="request"/>        
                                <parameter name="extension" value=".jwr"/>      
                             </handler>    
                    </requestFlow>]]></replacetoken>
    <replacevalue><![CDATA[<requestFlow>      
                               <handler type="java:com.as.webservices.TS9TicketTokenSender">        
                                 <parameter name="scope" value="session"/>      
                               </handler>      
                                <handler name="_wss4j_as_receiver_handler" type="java:com.as.security.asWSSReceiverHandler">        
                                    <parameter name="action" value="NoSecurity"/>      
                                </handler>    
                                <handler type="java:com.cm.ChangeHandler"/>
                                <handler type="java:com.cm.WSLoggingHandler"/>
                         </requestFlow>
                         <responseFlow>      
                         <handler type="java:com.as.webservices.TS9TicketTokenSender"/>      
                         <handler name="_wss4j_as_sender_handler" type="java:com.as.security.asWSSSenderHandler">        
                            <parameter name="signatureKeyIdentifier" value="IssuerSerial"/>        
                         <parameter name="encryptionKeyIdentifier" value="IssuerSerial"/>        
                         <parameter name="action" value="NoSecurity"/>      
                         </handler>    
                         <handler type="java:com.cm.WSLoggingHandler"/>
                        </responseFlow>  
   ]]></replacevalue>
</replace>
```

Now this gives correct results when run on unix machine, and token is successfully replaced by replace value but somehow the replacement does not take place on my windows machine.

Kindly help with issue identification and **alternate method to do so**. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using ant's `replaceregexp` task.
identified the first content between `<requestFlow>....</requestFlow>` in `match` attribute and added the replaced value in `replace` attribute of `replaceregexp` task